# Creating encryption for cheap secret cameras

Tags: video, encryption, camera, sd-card

I have a friend who uses small, cheap cameras for filming human rights abuses. I am interested in finding a method to write software or firmware to modify standard "gum" secret cameras such as the ones below. The idea is that as the footage is taken it is encrypted on the SD immediately after filming is stopped. The footage can then only be decrypted when the file is accessed, using a password. The encryption would need to be strong, so AES256 or equivalent.

http://www.pluc.fr/2010/02/tear-down-and-hacking-around-gumpack-camera/

What is everyones thoughts on the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [BigCam](http://unaligned.org/bigcam/index.php) project?

> The camera is constructed of openly available components, the designs and software are open source, and the mechanical form factor integrates into ThorLabs' 60mm cage system.

**EDIT #1:**

I had a deeper look at this project and after reflection this wouldn't be the way I would go.

First you will have to purchase all the components - assuming all of them are still produced and sold - and weld them. Then you only have a 2MB ROM on the board so saving video will be kind of *difficult* (You will either have to include additional storage capability or use another device to command the camera and store the data). And also find a decent power supply, get the non free IDE required to build the FW, building a cover, etc.

But what about using an Android device? You should be able to implement the encryption at a much more higher level. Plus there is plenty of development board over there if you want to build your own one. Have a look at this blog post [LI-5M03 camera on Beagleboard-xM](http://blog.galemin.com/2011/04/li-5m03-camera-on-beagleboard-xm/).

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting project. Any ideas about how to begin thinking about building encryption into the firmware?